# AppleScript for Extracting Email MS Outlook 2016 and saving it to Excel

Tags: excel, outlook, applescript

Need help in figuring out how to extract content from an email on MS Outlook, and saving it on MS Excel. I tried below but I'm getting stuck with figuring out how to select the specific email folder of an inbox I want to extract from.

Hope someone could help.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    set LinkRemoval to make new workbook

    set theSheet to active sheet of LinkRemoval

    set formula of range "D1" of theSheet to "Message"

    set formula of range "C1" of theSheet to "Subject"

    set formula of range "B1" of theSheet to "From"

    set formula of range "A1" of theSheet to "Date"

end tell



tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    activate

    set myAccount to exchange account 2

    set theMessages to messages of inbox
    set theRow to 2


    repeat with aMessage in theMessages

        my SetDate(date received of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)

        my SetFrom(sender of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)

        my SetSubject(subject of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)

        my SetMessage(content of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)

        set theRow to theRow + 1

    end repeat

end tell



on SetDate(theDate, theRow, theSheet)

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"

        set theRange to "A" & theRow

        set formula of rangetheRange of theSheet to theDate

    end tell

end SetDate



on SetFrom(theSender, theRow, theSheet)

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"

        set theRange to "B" & theRow

        set formula of rangetheRange of theSheet to theSender

    end tell

end SetFrom



on SetSubject(theSubject, theRow, theSheet)

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"

        set theRange to "C" & theRow

        set formula of rangetheRange of theSheet to theSubject

    end tell

end SetSubject



on SetMessage(theMessage, theRow, theSheet)

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"

        set theRange to "D" & theRow

        set formula of rangetheRange of theSheet to theMessage

    end tell

end SetMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
set theAccount to the first exchange account whose user name is "xxxxxxxx"

```
set topFolder to mail folder "Inbox" of theAccount
set subFolder to mail folder "xxxxx" of topFolder





set theMessages to messages of subFolder whose time received > xxxxx
```